# Using Google Sheets populated by Google Forms to send an email for every new response

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-forms

Saw a few similar options on SO but nothing that quite helps.

I run a team of several teams in which they fill out a [Google Form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1KdI1dTgZBNlZPUbSJ4BJRwEDMzJT-hDs3z--3e-rp30/edit?usp=sharing). They populate a [Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14iHOal1kxvKdeTTROShXH7hpBwjkOQNZ8QAr0f3mznU/edit?usp=sharing) and I would like to have a list of Emails (sheet 2) receive an email containing all of the responses for every response.

The email would look like a bold version of each question and beneath is the response. The information in the email should pertain to their response in Column F. Ideally you have a title of the email as "FORM ABC - DATE - Submitter" or "COLUMN F - COLUMN E - COLUMN C".

Currently I have 1 form for every team and the goal is the team supervisor gets an email when their Team submits a response (Found in COLUMN D). If this cannot be done I can just make several forms which are unique to each team.

*EDIT: There will be more columns added for more questions for each form section.

I found this online for the Google Sheets Script Editor but I do not know javascript but I believe I can adjust this for my needs.

```
function sendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2; // Start at second row because the first row contains the data labels
  var numRows = 3; // Put in here the number of rows you want to process

  // Fetch the range of cells A2:B4
  // Column A = Email Address, Column B = First Name
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 2)

  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (i in data) {
   var row = data[i];
   var emailAddress = row[0]; // First column of selected data
   var message = "Hey " + row[1] + ",\n how are you doing today?"; // Assemble the body text
   var subject = "Sending emails from a Spreadsheet";
   MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
  }
}
```

Comment: This is google apps script. Paste this into the winodw that pops up in Tools -> Script Editor. It's basically javascript but with an interface to many google apps. Also the script must be run manually by you. I belive there is a way to trigger the script to run upon some certain action using something called "triggers".

Comment: Correct; this was an example I found online. I need to adjust it to do specifically what I need however I do not know javascript :/

Comment: I think the easiest way would be if each team leader is the owner of their respective form. This way they can receive an email every time the form is submitted, and also look at the global results. All of this without the need of programming.

Comment: @Jescanellas okay yes; however I need the contents of the email to contain the responses not a link. Additionally, there are several people who need to receive each response.

Answer (score 0):

My solution consists in creating an HTML table from the Sheet with the responses of the Form, group them by Team and send them to the corresponding Supervisors.

> This won't run when a new response is registered, only manually. It's not possible for the triggers to send an email. See [Trigger Restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable).

```
function main(){

  var sprsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var supervisors = sprsheet.getSheetByName("Sheet2").getDataRange().getValues(); //Gets all the data from Sheet 2
  var data = sprsheet.getSheetByName("Form Responses 4").getDataRange().getValues(); //Same for Form Responses 4

  for (var i = 1; i < supervisors.length; i++){
    var counter = 0;
    var table;
    var header = "<table border=1><th>TimeStamp</th><th>Submitter email</th><th>Submitter</th><th>Team</th><th>Date</th><th>Which form is this?</th><th>Did you walk the walk?</th><th>Did you talk the talk?</th><th>Did you love me?</th><th>Do you want to squeez me?</th>";

    for (var j = 1; j < data.length; j++){ 

      if (supervisors[i][2] == data[j][3]){ //Teams are located at cols C and D respectively 
        table = createTable(data, header);
        counter++;
      }

    }
    if (counter > 0){
      var subject = "Sendimg emails from a Spreadsheet";
      var message = "<html><body>Hey " + supervisors[i][0] + ",\n how are you doing today? <br>";  
      table += "</table></body></html>";

      MailApp.sendEmail({
        to: supervisors[i][1], 
        subject: subject,
        htmlBody: message + table});  
    }
  }

}

function createTable(data, table){ 

  var cells = [];  
  //The table is a 2D array
  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++){
    cells = data[i]; //puts each cell in an array position
    table += "<tr>"; //Row starts

    for (var u = 0; u < cells.length; u++){
      table += "<td>"+ cells[u] +"</td>"; //New column
    }
    table += "</tr>"; //Row ends
  }
  return table
}
```

**References**

- [MailApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app)